# VisualStudio NUnit3TestAdapter testing project with third party dlls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit-3.0

I have a testing project `Proj_Test` with two nuget packages.

```
<packages>
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

`Proj_Test` has a reference to the tested project `Proj`.
[image: Layout]

`Proj` has references to several other dlls that need to be loaded.
Where can I add this information so that I can start the tests using the NUnit3TestAdapter from within my IDE without actually copying the dlls to the output folder.

There was [a solution for the Nunit2 Runners](https://nunit.org/index.php?p=multiAssembly&r=2.6.4). But I fail when attempting to use that for Nunit3 via NUnit3TestAdapter.

According to the [tips and tricks section](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Tips-And-Tricks) i added a settings file `Test.runsettings` via the menu.

```
<RunSettings>
  <NUnit>
    <PrivateBinPath>D:\Drive\AnyThirdParty</PrivateBinPath>
  </NUnit>
</RunSettings>
```

The setting seems to be ignored.

How can I manage these dependencies for my tests?

EDIT:
[This is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath(v=vs.110).aspx) what happened to me I think.

> Private assemblies are deployed in the same directory structure as the application. If the directories specified for PrivateBinPath are not under ApplicationBase, they are ignored.

Is creating a copy really the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find anything better,try to resolve it yourself

```
using ConsoleApplication6;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
           AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
           currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyResolveEventHandler;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1() { Assert.AreEqual(new MyClass().DoSomething(), 1); }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2() { Assert.AreEqual(new MyClass().DoSomething(), 1); }

        private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            return Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\MyPath\MyAssembly.dll");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately assembly probing works only on subdirectories so you can't use it...

Comment: I looked into 'AssemblyResolve' and it seems like you need to seperate the calls on a by method basis. So I tried it in 'OneTimeSetUp' but the event is not fired - anything that I could be missing?

Comment: @Johannes I can't think of a reason.I'll try it later when I get home

Comment: I think one one my dependencies is a native dll. that may be related to it.

Comment: @Johannes I don't see a problem with TestInitialize...Try adding a breakpoint and a try/catch in MyResolveEventHandler and check which assembly is failing to load(see args.Name) and why

Comment: I tried setting it up. My static method responsible to register completes and the testmethod is called afterwards. Resolution fails instantly with the first sub method in the test without the registered method beeing called.

Comment: @Johannes Can you replicate the issue in one small project and upload it somewhere?

Comment: I am still trying. I can not reproduce it using managed dlls. It is somehow connected to the interaction with native dlls. I can get a different failure using native dlls but i can not match my exact exception.

Comment: ok - so working on my minimal example i noticed that a) your code works for managed assemblies and b) i need to set the path for native dlls. Using the function AddDllDirectories is not trivial so i am using SetDllDirectories for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to George Vovos answer, this is what I ended up implementing.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

//https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute
//A SetUpFixture outside of any namespace provides SetUp and TearDown for the entire assembly.

[SetUpFixture]
class GlobalSetup
{

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetDllDirectory(string NewDirectory);

    static HashSet<string> directories = new HashSet<string>
    {
        @"D:\Drive\AnyThirdParty\"
    };

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
        AddManagedHandler();
        SetNativeDirectories();
    }

    private void SetNativeDirectories()
    {
        if(directories.Count() != 1)
        {
            //TODO: add support for multiple directories
            throw new NotImplementedException("current implementation only supports exactly one directory");
        }

        if (0 == SetDllDirectory(directories.First()))
        {
            throw new Exception("SetDllDirectory failed with error " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
    }

    private void AddManagedHandler()
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    }

    private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> candidates = FindCandidates(new AssemblyName(args.Name));
        return Assembly.LoadFrom(candidates.First());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> FindCandidates(AssemblyName assemblyname)
    {
        List<string> candidates = new List<string>();
        foreach (var path in directories)
        {
            string candidate = string.Format(@"{0}{1}.dll", path, assemblyname.Name);
            if (File.Exists(candidate))
            {
                candidates.Add(candidate);
            }
        }
        if (!candidates.Any())
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("Can not find assembly: '{0}.dll'", assemblyname.Name));
        }
        return candidates;
    }
}
```